# iOS : How to get updated version of cocoapods in swift

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have created my own Cocoapod. When I released a new version, then it should be available for the users. I have pushed the latest changes to git Cocoapods repository. Then I ran the command:

```
pod update
```

It showing the message for latest version update. But I am not getting the changes in my pod.

Comment: if you are installing the pods with `pod install` then you also need to use `pod install --repo-update`  to get latest versions of a pod. Also check if you're specifying a certain version of your current pod in your Podfile.

Comment: I am running 'pod update' command in terminal. I have not specified version in podfile. Now i run the command as you suggested but still same issue. Latest changes are not coming.

Comment: Are you sure your pod is properly released? You should see the expected pod version under releases tab in GitHub

Comment: Yes, Pod version is released successfully. I got the message on terminal during release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Run this command in terminal to update pod repo in your system

```
pod repo update
```

2: Then run

```
pod deintegrate
pod clean
pod install
```

Comment: thanks. It' s working. I did one more things additional along with your suggestion. I have removed the derived data and then run these commands.

Comment: Yes bro, 101%. That's why I voted your answers as well.

Comment: I am unable to understand the activity of acceptance of answers. Please send me mail with screenshot. So that i can do the needful. I am thinking, if you answered, then it should be automatically accepted. You can share the acceptance screenshots at talk2vipin89@gmail.com